# Add Multi select to filter list using JS

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I need to add a multi select button to filter my list in HTML output. Currently I have tried this search bar that is also not working.

Now I have tried the following but I get an error stating `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at myFunction (search.js:12)"`

my HTML:

```
<div class="container" >
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
  {% for key, values in data4.iteritems() %}
    <h3> {{key}} </h3>
    <ul id="myUL">
      {% for client in values %}
        <li>{{ client[25] }} - {{ client[13] }} -  {{ client[16] }} - <b>Nights/Days</b> - {{ client[21] }} - <b>Adults</b> - {{ client[0] }} - <b>Children</b> - {{ client[1] }} - <b>Status</b> - {{ client[3] }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="container">
```

My JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: It works on stackoverflow's compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the problem in this line

```
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

There should anchor tag to point getElementsByTagName But it seems that there is no anchor

Comment: Correct ! I spotted that now Thank you ! I am editing my code, But it is still not completely right. I will post my semi-working code now

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what snehi56 said was correct. I got the search functionality to work now by doing the following, however its not hiding everything it should yet.

New edited HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
                                            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()"
                                                   placeholder="Search for names..">


                                            {% for key, values in data4.iteritems() %}
                                            <div class="booking-reference">
                                                <h3> {{key}} </h3>
                                                <ul id="myUL">
                                                    {% for client in values %}
                                                    <li><span>{{ client[25] }}</span> - {{ client[13] }} - {{
                                                        client[16] }} - <b>Nights/Days</b> - {{ client[21] }} - <b>Adults</b>
                                                        - {{ client[0] }} - <b>Children</b> - {{ client[1] }} - <b>Status</b>
                                                        - {{ client[3] }}
                                                    </li>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            {% endfor %}

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="container">
```

Edited JS:

```
function myFunction() {
// Declare variables
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
var bookings =  $(".booking-reference");
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
        console.log(a, a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter));
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

So this does not give an error anymore and it searches as it should. However I think because I am using a loop to iterate through my results in HTML it is not hiding all the unmatched items as it should after the {{keys}

I think I should hide the whole div "which im calling booking-reference" but not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

You can give Id or name to your div and hide it using JS.

```
var x = document.getElementById('booking-reference-div');
x.style.display = 'block'; //none
```